# How to embed Windows Media Player ( WMV) Movie in HTML?

Tags: html, cross-browser, wmv

I am following the code from http://www.alistapart.com/articles/byebyeembed/  and it is working fine in Firex 4.0 but It is not working at all in IE9. I, even, cannot play the movie by pressing play button.

```
  <object id='MediaPlayer1' width="320" height="285" classid='CLSID:22d6f312-b ... >

  <param name='fileName' value="src.wmv">

  <param name='animationatStart' value='true'>

  <param name='transparentatStart' value='true'>

  <param name='autoStart' value="false">

  <param name='showControls' value="true">

  <param name='loop' value="true">

  <param name="wmode" value="transparent">

  <embed type='application/x-mplayer2'

    pluginspage='http://microsoft.com/windows/mediaplayer/en/download/'

    id='MediaPlayer2' name='mediaPlayer' displaysize='4' autosize='-1'

    bgcolor='darkblue' showcontrols="true" showtracker='-1'

    showdisplay='0' showstatusbar='-1' videoborder3d='-1' width="522" height="350"

    src="src.wmv" autostart="true" designtimesp='5311' loop="true" )

  </embed>

  </object>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will surely have your answer :)  I was going to type it out here for you, but its already here!

[Embedding Windows Media Player for all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164/embedding-windows-media-player-for-all-browsers)

Comment: it works great but some users have reported that it doesn't play on their browsers... so there is an issue.