# How to stream MMS Protocol Radio on your Website?

Tags: javascript, html, xml, flash, plugins

Is it possible to stream a radio channel in my website if I have the mml url mms:// ?  I was checking out XML Flash Players but they do not seem to support that protocol.  I am also ok if I need to code something but I would like to be guided in the right direction as I cannot find a lot of information about this issue.

Is there something ready made? Would it be easier if I get my client to get me a different type of stream?

Comment: Your site wouldn't be doing the streaming. it'd be the client's browser. All your site would be doing is embedding the mms url in an appropriate object/media/whatever  tag.

Comment: @MarcB - You are right, but I would still need something to play them with, and that is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You need to address the Windows Media Player on the users systems, because Flash does not support MMS streaming at all. According to the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164/embedding-windows-media-player-for-all-browsers) it works in that way (you need to replace `./test.wmv` by your mms-URL:

```
 <object id="mediaplayer" classid="clsid:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#version=5,1,52,701" standby="loading microsoft windows media player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" width="320" height="310">
     <param name="filename" value="/test.wmv">
     <param name="animationatstart" value="true">
     <param name="transparentatstart" value="true">
     <param name="autostart" value="true">
     <param name="showcontrols" value="true">
     <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
     <param name="windowlessvideo" value="true">
     <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="./test.wmv" autostart="true" showcontrols="true" showstatusbar="1" bgcolor="white" width="320" height="310">
</object>
```

You also can play around with the configuration values and hide parts of the player as you want it.

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, this is very close to what I want. However I would like, if possible, to have it integrated in the website, and not open in an external player, can this be done?

Comment: This embeds the player into the DOM and does not open a new window or something

Comment: Ok, that works in IE, but does not in chrome that's why I thought it's not opening internally at first.  What the best solution here?

Comment: Is there really no player in Chrome or is it not playing?

Comment: There is no player visible in Chrome or Firefox in this case, however in chrome it asks to open it externally.

Comment: I added the type attribute to embed tag. Please try, if this works