# Embed wmv in all Chrome, IE and Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, embed

The code below works in IE, Firefox but not Chrome.  What change is necessary to make it work in Chrome.  Chrome says "No plug-in available to display this content". 
I got the code from:
[Embedding Windows Media Player for all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164/embedding-windows-media-player-for-all-browsers)

```
<object id="mediaplayer" classid="clsid:22d6f312-b0f6-11d0-94ab-0080c74c7e95" codebase="http://activex.microsoft.com/activex/controls/mplayer/en/nsmp2inf.cab#version=5,1,52,701" standby="loading microsoft windows media player components..." type="application/x-oleobject" width="320" height="310">
<param name="filename" value="./test.wmv">
 <param name="animationatstart" value="true">
 <param name="transparentatstart" value="true">
 <param name="autostart" value="true">
 <param name="showcontrols" value="true">
 <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="true">
 <param name="windowlessvideo" value="true">
 <embed src="./test.wmv" autostart="true" showcontrols="true" showstatusbar="1" bgcolor="white" width="320" height="310">
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to download the plugin for WMV files on the client side. That means that for anyone who visits the site with Chrome will need to have already [installed the Chrome plugin locally](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95697?hl=en).

HTML5 Video/Flash video may be a better way to accomplish this and make it seamless for the user. [Here's an example for HTML 5 video](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/video/basics/)