# Embedding WMV file into Html and making it work in most of the browsers

Tags: html, video, embedded-resource, wmv

I was asked to embed a `wmv` file into a piece of `html`.

So far so good, googling on how to do it quickly reveals that this is achieved using html tags `object` and `embed`.

My problem is that the sample I set up (shown below) is only working in IE. Chrome displays a a gray box with the message "This plugin is not supported", and following the help that shows up turns out chrome does not play NPAPI plug-ins anymore. Firefox shows nothing whatsoever, not even the object frame.

I researched a bit for workarounds to play it on chrome notwithstanding the fact google stopped supporting it sometime on 2015.

Messing with `chrome://flags/#enable-npapi` looked promising (as suggested [here](https://allinlearning.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/204245434-Re-enabling-NPAPI-Plugins-in-Google-Chrome-After-Early-April-of-2015)), but I can't find a `enable Npapi` among my flags.

Anyone knows how to have it working at least in Chrome, Firefox and IE ?

Is it possible to (freely) convert a `wvm` to `Html5 video` ?

```
<Html>
<Head></Head>

<Body>

  <object id="MediaPlayer" width="192" height="190" type="video/x-ms-asf">
    <param name="FileName"value="D:/myVideo.wmv">
    <param name="autostart" value="false">
    <param name="ShowControls" value="true">
    <param name="ShowStatusBar" value="false">
    <param name="ShowDisplay" value="false">
    <embed type="application/x-mplayer2" src="D:/myVideo.wmv"
        width="192" height="190" ShowControls="1" ShowStatusBar="0" ShowDisplay="0" autostart="0" />
</object>

</Body>
</Html>
```

Comment: 2 possible resources for help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23836514/embed-wmv-in-all-chrome-ie-and-firefox /// https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/chrome/e4jDZEegQSo

Comment: @J.DKYSR: Thanks, indeed I spotted the 1st link afterwards, although it did not receive much attention/not get much activity. I am trying converting it into Html 5 video.

Answer (score 1):

There are any number of resources that will convert your wmv to mp4/ogg/other types of cross-browser format, including http://video.online-convert.com/convert-to-mp4, however thats beside the point.

If you want to display the video in html5, you should really use the `<video>`
tag.

An example of this would be

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<video width="320" height="240" controls>
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  <source src="movie.webm" type="video/webm">
  Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes Rachel, I have just tried it (and was going to post it as an answer) - but did not because this will not work in IE. Will work in chrome, however. In Firefox, still not. By the way I ended up using exactly the same url to convert as you suggest. My answer looked exactly like this :) (the same html 5 video excerpt :)

Comment: @Veverke the video tag is supported in ie11+

Comment: Mine is 11, I am getting "Invalid Souce" inside the video frame.

Comment: @Veverke ensure you have the correct (preferably full) path specified for the video

Comment: @Veverke also ensure the video file is not corrupt (i.e. fully converted before you upload it. Just click to play to test it.

Comment: @Veverke i just tested a fiddle in ie11 and it worked fine https://jsfiddle.net/RachGal/0yrn9owh/

Comment: @Veverke as for firefox, caniuse list that it's supported from vsn 45; i have 43.2 and it ran fine

Comment: Thanks for all the updates Rachel, I am still unable to have it working in IE... I am giving the full path, just like in the working version for chrome. I tried adding video/webm (.webm) format to the MIME Types supported by my IIS, like suggested in other posts, but still no deal.

Comment: @veverke if that is the case I would check your doctype to ensure it is in fact html5, it should read !doctype html , then compare your code to my fiddle and see if there are any blatent errors that stand out. Check the doctype first though. Sorry for late reply, was eating!

Comment: @Veverke cheers, It really bugs me when something seemingly simple proves difficult!

Comment: I was indeed missing the doctype that tells it is html5, but... no progress, stayed the same. Will get back to this later. Thanks.